# Ionic FilePath not working, how to get the file path for Android 11

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, uri, filepath

I've read about all the changes in the File system for Android, because of Android 11.

Here is my problem. I'm opening a file using `Android File Chooser` from `Ionic`.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser

```
 this.androidFileChooser
        .open({ mime: 'application/pdf' })
        .then((file) => {
```

This gives me this response : `"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/11654"`.

The problem is that I need to get the real location of the file to convert it to base 64, and send it with a POST Request to the client server.
So before all these problems, I was using Android File Path from Ionic : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path

```
this.filePath.resolveNativePath(file).then((filePath) => {
```

And I was receiving `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pdffile.pdf`
Using this, I could transform it in base64 and everything worked well.

Now, it returns me nothing for Android 11. So All the process can't work if I don't have this filepath.

Do you have a solution for Angular/Ionic, to get the file Path for a file, for Android 11? This is very problematic.

Comment: No you do not need a 'real location'. If you had a 'real location' you would use a FileInputStream to read the file. But you can use an InputStream for that uri directly and then read from the stream as you were used before. Do it allways. Hence also below 10.

Comment: The problem is, I need to base64 this file, and the Base64 plugin is waiting for a path starting with ```file:/// ...```. And my client wants to receive a base64 encoded string. I need to handle this in the mobile App side. Could you show me an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Ok. But then it makes no sense to give an example. Then copy the file from the obtained uri to a file system location first and use that path. But... Why do you need a plugin for base64 encoding in this way?

Comment: This is a long story. Actually, we were using Chooser plugin. But the mimetype doesn't work for Android, and we need to respect the client expectations. So i'm handling the upload for iOS on one side, and Android on the other side. But the Android File Chooser doesn't give the data URI like Chooser. I had to use ```FilePath``` and then ```Base64``` on the result of File Path.

Could you develop your solution? Should I use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file ?

Comment: Sorry i do not use Cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches, it seems that Cordova doesn't target API 30 and the new changes in its scope. To solve my problem, I use Ionic Chooser, but using this one is problematic for the mimetype for Android (It allows to upload images from Google Drive when you set the mimetype to application/pdf).
That's a loss for a win. I hope Cordova plugins maintainers will bring some solutions to these changes.

Answer (score 1):

you need following plugin to install

1. @ionic-native/file-path'
2. @ionic-native/file-chooser

and it will give you

url:  content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A29570

path: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/flutter.pdf

```
      this.fileChooser
      .open()
      .then(url => {
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(url)
          .then(filePath => {
                console.log('saif file pathhh',filePath);
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('saif file pathhh errorrr',err));
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('saif file pathhh errorrr catchhh',e);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my Ionic 5 apps, tested on Android 11.

First I call `getAsWebViewCorrectUrlMobile` below in my app to get a reference to  a local file, then I can convert that to base64 or whatever by getting its content.

```
      var url = this.getAsWebViewCorrectUrlMobile(inputFileUrl);
        
      this._http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise().then(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }).catch(err => {
        if (err.status == 404) {
          alert('Could not find video file: ' + url);
        }
        resolve(null);
      });
```

File method:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public _platform: Platform) {
    //...
}

getAsWebViewCorrectUrlMobile(fileUri: string) {
    if (this._platform.is('ios')) {
        return window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(fileUri);
    }
    else {
        // correct file paths on Android due to https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/598
        var filePathCorrected = window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(fileUri);
        filePathCorrected = filePathCorrected.replace('file:/', "https://localhost/_app_file_/");
        return filePathCorrected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answser. I'm getting my URI from Chooser like this: ```"uri":"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A18"```
                          Then I do ```this.webView.convertFileSrc(file.uri);``` and it returns me this : 
```http://localhost/_capacitor_content_/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A18```
I didn't apply your filepath correction, because there isn't ```file:/```
If I base 64 the returned path, it gives me nothing

Comment: This isn't working